# Uncheck "use trusted connection" checkbox through vba

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have to run a macro in Access 2007 that connects to a SQL server and I use a connection string to do that.

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
'Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset


Dim strConn As String

'cnPubs.ConnectionTimeout = 10

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.

strConn = strConn & "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=MyDataSource;INITIAL CATALOG=InitCat;"

strConn = strConn & "User Id=MyID;"

strConn = strConn & "Password=MyPassword;"

strConn = strConn & "INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

strConn = strConn & "Trusted_connection=no;"

conn.ConnectionString = strConn

conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways

conn.Open
```

The problem is that everytime it tries to connect, the "use trusted connection" checkbox that appears is checked and I have to uncheck it because I don't use the login and password of the pc user to connect. Is there a way to automatically uncheck it through vba, where I define connection string? I've tried to use

```
Trusted_connection=no
```

but it keeps appearing checked.
I want to do that because I want to delete

```
conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
```

and make the macro connect with the database without need of any kind of human interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line asks for Windows authentication.  Remove it from your connection string if you want to provide user and password for SQL Server authentication.

```
strConn = strConn & "INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that could be related to that, I was so focused on the "trusted connection" property that it doesn't even went through my mind.